# The AC will not get cold unless driving

Tags: ac, fan, jaguar

The fan in front of my radiator is not turning on. my cars AC does not get cold unless im driving over 30 mph. any solutions? 2007 Jaguar X-Type

Comment: Have you tested the fans themselves? Have you checked the relays to the fans?

Answer (score 3):

Fix the fan.

At low speeds, the fan pulls air through the radiator (and AC condensor) and cools things off. At higher speeds, airflow takes care of that, and the fan is useless. That probably explains why everything works well when you're going faster.

If the fan is not turning on, it could be a few things. Some that come to mind:

1. Wiring harness is disconnected from the fan. You might be surprised how often this happens.
2. Bad fan motor. This would likely involve replacing the entire assembly, but I haven't looked at details for your specific car.
3. Bad temp sensor.
4. Hilarious, but I've accidentally done this: swapped wires when splicing the wiring harness near the fan so that it's spinning backwards, blowing hot engine bay air through the radiator instead of pulling in nice cool-ish air from the outside.

That's all that comes to mind. A competent shop should be able to narrow it down quickly. Do NOT let them sell you a new AC compressor, condenser, refrigerant, high/low pressure lines, etc.

Comment: Also, a bad high pressure switch if it's a fixed displacement ac compressor. The condenser/cooling fan is also actuated by the high pressure switch when AC is on.

Answer (score 1):

The jag x type has a fan control unit which can be a source of many cooling fan problems -I have a jag x type...

You may find that you get more accurate responses by going to a Jag forum : I use www.jaguarforum.com and the people on there are very knowledgeable as they all have x-types and there are some threads about fans already.